# Is there a way to select more than one option in django admin filters?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I actually have two questions, please answer what you can:

Question 1:

In django admin, if you have `list_filters = ["book"]`, and your options were `"red carpet"` & `"Bingo the Dinosaur"`, you can only select one book at a time; either `"red carpet"` or `"Bingo the Dinosaur"`. Is there a way to make it so that the user can select both at the same time?

Question 2:

In django admin is there a way to combine `list_filter` fields? so if you have `list_filer = [" bookname", "bookauthor"]`, is there a way to make it so that the book name and author are combined in one filter and you search it at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question:

I think it's possible. I've made a quick test on the admin interface for Users, and if you play with the URL querystring, you can combine filters : `/admin/auth/user/?is_superuser=1&is_superuser=0` will list both super and non-super users.

You'll have to override admin filters template to generate proper URLs for your needs, though.

I don't understand your second question. What do you mean by combined ? If you select an item in the first filter and an item in the second one, you will have combined filtering, won't you ?

Comment: thank you first off. So what i mean by combined is instead of having two different filter lists for bookname and bookauthor, its all under one list so it would be like choosing both fiter options at once. In terms of the first where would I be messing with the URL?

Comment: If it's all under one list if you have 10 books and 10 authors, that would mean 100 list items. I still don't understand how it can be useful, maybe you should provide a picture of what you want. For the first question, related templates are in [`django.contrib.admin.templates`](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin). [`filter.html`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/filter.html) should be the one.